# How to keep the styles of a graph when refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, plugins, chart.js

I need help because I am having a problem with my graph

I am using chartjs-node-canva which is a version of chartjs to use in nodejs as an easy way to use the library from the backend. What I am doing is converting the graph into an image and then I place it in my HTML template

So far so good, my problem is that when I load the template for the first time the styles that I have configured for my chart are shown as I expect them to be,

[image: image1]

but when I refresh the page, that is where the problem starts because everything is out of sync.

[image: image2]

I really don't know what's going on and why this is happening, does anyone have an idea how I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance, any kind of help will be greatly appreciated, have a very nice day.

** CODE **

```
  const canvasRenderService = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({
            width: 860,
            height: 539,
            chartCallback: (ChartJS) => {
                ChartJS.register(require('chartjs-plugin-datalabels'))
            }
        });

        const subLabels = {
            id: 'subLabels',
            afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
                const { ctx, chartArea: { left, right, top, bottom, width, height } } = chart;

                ctx.save();
                subLabelText('DEV', width / 4 * 1.6);
                subLabelText('SAC', width / 4 * 3.1);
                subLabelText('DESIGN', width / 4 * 3.9);

                function subLabelText(text, x) {
                    ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)';
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.fillText(text, x + left, bottom + 144);
                    let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
                    let xCenter = (xAxis.left + xAxis.right) / 1.45;
                    let yBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
                    [xAxis.left, xCenter, xAxis.right].forEach(AxisX => {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(AxisX, yBottom);
                        ctx.lineTo(AxisX, yBottom + 110);
                        ctx.stroke();
                    });

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
                    ctx.moveTo(width / 4 * 3.95, yBottom);
                    ctx.lineTo(width / 4 * 3.95, yBottom + 120);
                    ctx.stroke();

                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }
        }

        const mkChart = await canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer({
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    label: '% ACTIVITY',
                    backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
                    borderColor: '#FF7605',
                    data: lineBar,
                    datalabels: {
                        anchor: 'start',
                        align: 'center',
                        clamp: true,
                        backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
                        color: 'white',
                        font: {
                            weight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'WEEKLY SUMMARY OF HOURS',
                    backgroundColor: '#222A35',
                    borderColor: '#222A35',
                    data: barHorizontal,
                    datalabels: {
                        rotation: 270,
                        padding: 10,
                        anchor: 'start',
                        align: 'end'
                    },
                    barPercentage: 0.5
                },
                {
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'HOURS',
                    backgroundColor: '#008582',
                    borderColor: '#008582',
                    data: colbWeekly,
                    datalabels: {
                        anchor: 'end',
                        align: 'top',
                        clamp: true,
                        backgroundColor: '#008582',
                        color: 'white',
                        font: {
                            weight: 'bold'
                        }
                    },
                    barPercentage: 0.5
                }]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        color: 'white',
                        font: {
                            weight: 'bold'
                        },
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'AVERAGE WEEKLY HOURS'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                        labels: {
                            padding: 30,
                            usePointStyle: true
                        }
                    },
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        fill: false
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    'x-axis-0': {
                        stacked: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 80,
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 20,
                            minRotation: 90,
                        },
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        // barPercentage: 0.2
                    },
                    'y-axis-0': {
                        grid: {
                            drawOnChartArea: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            plugins: [subLabels]

        });
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 0.80rem !important;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

@page {
  margin: 10mm;
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
}

.Logo {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
const apidata = [{
    "id": 6430591403,
    "task_id": 110578536,
    "user_id": 854500,
    "keyboard": 872,
    "mouse": 2123,
    "input_tracked": 20149,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 20149,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T17:40:03.167232Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T11:00:24.381152Z",
    "username": "user1",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 24,
    "three_weekly_hours": 12,
    "summaryWeekly": 29149,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 2827,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 4,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 8,
    "percentageHours": 2.024236111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 2,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 8,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 2.025
  },
  {
    "id": 6418099795,
    "task_id": 110964243,
    "user_id": 1169488,
    "keyboard": 12454,
    "mouse": 21282,
    "input_tracked": 56867,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 634,
    "billable": 56867,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T14:12:47.422537Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:00:52.334795Z",
    "username": "user2",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 65867,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30906,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.574097222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 35,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.575
  },
  {
    "id": 6436682459,
    "task_id": 111277830,
    "user_id": 854472,
    "keyboard": 3650,
    "mouse": 53335,
    "input_tracked": 76184,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 76184,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:04:18.371347Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:12.456776Z",
    "username": "user3",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 76184,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 55852,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 21,
    "percentageHours": 5.290555555555556,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 18,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 2,
    "percentActivityW": 54,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 5.29
  },
  {
    "id": 6418143504,
    "task_id": 111039935,
    "user_id": 957706,
    "keyboard": 8128,
    "mouse": 26665,
    "input_tracked": 56130,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 56130,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T14:20:38.428547Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:00:53.895079Z",
    "username": "user4",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 56130,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 31989,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 16,
    "percentageHours": 3.8979166666666667,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 14,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 42,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.8975000000000004
  },
  {
    "id": 6436827335,
    "task_id": 110101015,
    "user_id": 854517,
    "keyboard": 5695,
    "mouse": 28077,
    "input_tracked": 62610,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 62610,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T16:51:44.533355Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:10.219855Z",
    "username": "user5",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 62610,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30715,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 17,
    "percentageHours": 4.347916666666666,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 37,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.3475
  },
  {
    "id": 6415607157,
    "task_id": 111238271,
    "user_id": 854471,
    "keyboard": 7295,
    "mouse": 14616,
    "input_tracked": 29633,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 1571,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 29633,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T06:17:06.580395Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:01:01.677261Z",
    "username": "user6",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 29633,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 19055,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 8,
    "percentageHours": 2.057847222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 16,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 31,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 2.0575
  },
  {
    "id": 6438865339,
    "task_id": 110014205,
    "user_id": 1171637,
    "keyboard": 11728,
    "mouse": 24895,
    "input_tracked": 70739,
    "manual": 1620,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 70739,
    "created_at": "2022-09-04T16:03:44.328404Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-05T11:00:31.972437Z",
    "username": "user7",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 72359,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30822,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 20,
    "percentageHours": 5.024930555555556,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 11,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 2,
    "percentActivityW": 31,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 5.0225
  },
  {
    "id": 6429724387,
    "task_id": 111040126,
    "user_id": 854493,
    "keyboard": 13205,
    "mouse": 30058,
    "input_tracked": 56630,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 56630,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T14:46:58.641008Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T11:00:13.064762Z",
    "username": "user8",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 56630,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 40044,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 16,
    "percentageHours": 3.932638888888889,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 18,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 74,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.9325
  },
  {
    "id": 6418215334,
    "task_id": 111232314,
    "user_id": 1726823,
    "keyboard": 11761,
    "mouse": 35504,
    "input_tracked": 73802,
    "manual": 862,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 74664,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T14:32:20.799309Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:00:48.637118Z",
    "username": "user9",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 74664,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 43021,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 21,
    "percentageHours": 5.185,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 14,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 1,
    "percentActivityW": 41,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 5.1850000000000005
  },
  {
    "id": 6436683187,
    "task_id": 110916251,
    "user_id": 957963,
    "keyboard": 2050,
    "mouse": 5530,
    "input_tracked": 13478,
    "manual": 1181,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 14659,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:05:12.543140Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T15:39:51.279106Z",
    "username": "user10",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 14659,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 7182,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 4,
    "percentageHours": 1.017986111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 12,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 1.0175
  },
  {
    "id": 6415608216,
    "task_id": 110169040,
    "user_id": 1476078,
    "keyboard": 23401,
    "mouse": 51185,
    "input_tracked": 99108,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 99108,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T06:17:26.341286Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T02:03:01.258835Z",
    "username": "user11",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 99108,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 67332,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 28,
    "percentageHours": 6.882499999999999,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 17,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 6,
    "percentActivityW": 48,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 6.885
  },
  {
    "id": 6436711920,
    "task_id": 111299925,
    "user_id": 1762379,
    "keyboard": 9260,
    "mouse": 27177,
    "input_tracked": 63034,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 63034,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:37:55.058824Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:09.826018Z",
    "username": "user12",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 63034,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 33416,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.377361111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 13,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 40,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.3774999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6438388730,
    "task_id": 111271635,
    "user_id": 1763812,
    "keyboard": 8023,
    "mouse": 34217,
    "input_tracked": 60716,
    "manual": 3056,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 63772,
    "created_at": "2022-09-04T06:11:14.526669Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:10.753741Z",
    "username": "user13",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 63772,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 39685,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.4286111111111115,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 16,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 66,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.4275
  },
  {
    "id": 6436711572,
    "task_id": 110962406,
    "user_id": 1512574,
    "keyboard": 13031,
    "mouse": 29149,
    "input_tracked": 58021,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 58021,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:37:32.555344Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:12.010515Z",
    "username": "user14",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 58021,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 35912,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 16,
    "percentageHours": 4.0292361111111115,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 15,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 46,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.0275
  },
  {
    "id": 6429845321,
    "task_id": 111275770,
    "user_id": 1597423,
    "keyboard": 7547,
    "mouse": 16932,
    "input_tracked": 45344,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 45344,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T15:02:22.445061Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T21:05:15.892875Z",
    "username": "user15",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 54344,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 21515,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 15,
    "percentageHours": 3.773888888888889,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 10,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 32,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.7724999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6429886569,
    "task_id": 111300959,
    "user_id": 1005008,
    "keyboard": 9124,
    "mouse": 23219,
    "input_tracked": 47335,
    "manual": 16930,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 64265,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T15:10:49.050765Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T15:37:15.995376Z",
    "username": "user16",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 64265,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30503,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.462847222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 47,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.4625
  },
  {
    "id": 6436728901,
    "task_id": 109755222,
    "user_id": 1846477,
    "keyboard": 9644,
    "mouse": 25906,
    "input_tracked": 64724,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 64724,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:57:43.250737Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T19:24:22.872994Z",
    "username": "user18",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 64724,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 29885,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.494722222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 34,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.495
  }
]

const maplabels = apidata.map(element => element.username);
const labels = maplabels;

// DataBar
const mapbarHorizontal = apidata.map(element => element.summaryHoursTrackedWeekly);
const barHorizontal = mapbarHorizontal;
// console.log('labels', barHorizontal);

// LineBar
const maplineBar = apidata.map(element => element.percentActivityW);
const lineBar = maplineBar;

// BarWeeklyHour Colaborador
const mapColbWeekly = apidata.map(element => element.three_weekly_hours);
const colbWeekly = mapColbWeekly;


const subLabels = {
  id: 'subLabels',
  afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea: {
        left,
        right,
        top,
        bottom,
        width,
        height
      }
    } = chart;

    ctx.save();
    subLabelText('DEV', width / 4 * 1.6);
    subLabelText('SAC', width / 4 * 3.1);
    subLabelText('DESIGN', width / 4 * 3.9);

    function subLabelText(text, x) {
      ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText(text, x + left, bottom + 144);
      let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      let xCenter = (xAxis.left + xAxis.right) / 1.45;
      let yBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
      [xAxis.left, xCenter, xAxis.right].forEach(AxisX => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(AxisX, yBottom);
        ctx.lineTo(AxisX, yBottom + 110);
        ctx.stroke();
      });

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
      ctx.moveTo(width / 4 * 3.95, yBottom);
      ctx.lineTo(width / 4 * 3.95, yBottom + 120);
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
}

const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        label: '% ACTIVITY',
        backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
        borderColor: '#FF7605',
        data: lineBar,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'start',
          align: 'center',
          clamp: true,
          backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'WEEKLY SUMMARY OF HOURS',
        backgroundColor: '#222A35',
        borderColor: '#222A35',
        data: barHorizontal,
        datalabels: {
          rotation: 270,
          padding: 10,
          anchor: 'start',
          align: 'end'
        },
        barPercentage: 0.5
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'HOURS',
        backgroundColor: '#008582',
        borderColor: '#008582',
        data: colbWeekly,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'top',
          clamp: true,
          backgroundColor: '#008582',
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        },
        barPercentage: 0.5
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'AVERAGE WEEKLY HOURS'
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        labels: {
          padding: 30,
          usePointStyle: true
        }
      },
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        fill: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      'x-axis-0': {
        stacked: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 80,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 20,
          minRotation: 90,
        },
        grid: {
          display: false
        },
        // barPercentage: 0.2
      },
      'y-axis-0': {
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [subLabels]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels">
</script>
<div>
  <div id="legend"></div>
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: `Hello how are you? Wishing you a pleasant day,` Do you really want to know ?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I didn't introduce myself correctly, I'm really sorry, I'm not very good with English but I really need help with something that I've been looking for a while and I know that this community is quite wide

Comment: I usually have the habit of greeting and introducing myself in this way, I think it is not correct in English: c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I managed to find the solution to my problem. As @LeeLenalee said, the chart is independent of what styles you maintain in your template and where you call your chart from.

The problem was that it was not registering the Datalabels plugin correctly. When I found the library it guided me a lot of examples so I was doing something like "require('chart.js')"

```
 chartCallback: (ChartJS) => {
                ChartJS.register(require('chartjs-plugin-datalabels'))
            }
```

I found a github thread that talked about this, but in diferent context so I turned to the documentation that specifies:

> "Let ChartJSNodeCanvas manage the lifecycle of the plugin itself, each
> instance will have a separate instance of the plugin"

```
 requireLegacy: ['chartjs-plugin-datalabels']
```

Thank you all very much for your immense help.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, did you use percent for the position of the texts? If your browser is in a different size, your old code will make the text look funky.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering me, add the MainCSS to the question, I have some general styles for the template and I also use Bootstrap to lay out a bit

Comment: This is not a CSS issue, it is being drawn on a canvas so CSS does not impact that

Comment: Yes! @LeeLenalee you are right! I found that it was the problem, I answered the question in case someone has the same problem.